# Modify UITableView appearance with an UISwitch located in another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a tabbed application. In the last tab I have an UISwitch and I want it to change the background of the UITableView located in the first tab. The switch is defined like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var darkModeSwitch: UISwitch!
```

then the action that sets the UserDefaults:

```
 @IBAction func setUserDefaults() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(darkModeSwitch.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
}
```

and the viewDidLoad of the last tab that reads from UserDefaults:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let switchState = defaults.bool(forKey: "switchState")
    darkModeSwitch.isOn = switchState
}
```

The UserDefaults part works. However, the thing mentioned in the title does not. I've tried setting a global variable:

```
var on = false
```

that changes to `true` with the following code in the IBAction:

```
if darkModeSwitch.isOn {
    on = true
}
```

and in the UITableView's viewDidLoad() :

```
if on == true {
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

but it doesn't do anything. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewDidLoad is only called once. If the viewcontroller is loaded before the button is hit then you can expect it to do nothing. If you kill the app and re-open it then you can expect to see the change. Try viewWillAppear to update the color. That method gets called every time the user navigates there and back.

Comment: Even after restarting the app the color is not changed. Are you sure that my code is correct?

Comment: Are you hitting the breakpoint at self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black? If so is switchState correct at darkModeSwitch.isOn = switchState?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in those places. Do you ever get to that breakpoint? If so is the value of switchState what you expect it?

Comment: What about the breakpoint in viewDidLoad? Check the value of switchState to make sure its correct. You may need to call NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize() after setting the new user default value

Comment: It does get to the breakpoint at `darkModeSwitch.isOn = switchState`. Calling synchronize() does not do anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "Check the value of switchState to make sure its correct"?

Comment: Solved the problem. switchState is an integer, not a bool.  That was the problem. Thank you for help!